# JSONB query won't stick into a view

Tags: postgresql, sql-view, jsonb

**What I have**

```
CREATE TABLE "1".events
(
  doc jsonb,
  id character varying(36),
)
```

The `doc` jsonb field contains a json like this

```
{ "id": "a", "sessions": [{"id":"1"}, {"id": "2"}, ..., {"id":"18"}] }
```

---

Now I want a view that gives me one row per session, so I write:

```
select e.id, obj FROM "1".events e, jsonb_array_elements(e.doc->'sessions') obj
```

Which works like a charm!

```
"e1" "{"id": "18"}"
...
```

What instead does **NOT WORK** is sticking this query inside a view

```
create or replace view events_session_v as 
(select e.id, obj FROM "1".events e, jsonb_array_elements(e.doc->'sessions') obj)

********** Error **********

ERROR: cannot change name of view column "?column?" to "id"
SQL state: 42P16
```

What's wrong in this create view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view `events_session_v` already exists and you cannot replace it if the return type is going to change. Use `drop view`:

```
drop view events_session_v;

create or replace view events_session_v as 
    select e.id, obj 
    from "1".events e, jsonb_array_elements(e.doc->'sessions') obj;
```

Comment: This was the case apparently, but man, the error message from postgres is really messed up.